# React player video does not stop on playing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-slick, react-player

I am using `React-Slick` for slider . Here in one one of my slider I have a video to play. I am able to play video using `React-Video` But the video plays even if we change slide

```
const [ isplaying, setIsplaying ] = useState(false)

     <div>
      <ReactPlayer
               key={`frame'-${media.id}`}
               width={IMAGE_WIDTH}
               height={IMAGE_HEIGHT}
               allowFullScreen={true}
               playing={isplaying}
               controls
               url={media.src}></ReactPlayer>
            )}
    </div>  
 
         <Slider
          className={isViewWide ? css.sliderRegularWide : css.sliderRegularNarrow}
          asNavFor={nav2}
          beforeChange={(currentIndex, nextIndex) => {
            if (currentIndex === 4) { setIsplaying(false)}
          }}
          ref={slider1 => setNav1(slider1)}
          {...settingsRegular}>
          {regularImages}
        </Slider>
```

Even after setting playing false the video does not stop playing.

Comment: I think you should probably use a React ref to pass to `Slider`. Can you share a more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example so we've more context?

Comment: https://github.com/cookpete/react-player/issues/1079